# Image sizes how to decide how big they should be SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, image, sprite-kit, size

So the internet is a sea of information only a foot deep, so here I am asking a question again.

SpriteKit, when making a game, how do you decide the size of your image assets?

I have a few examples and curious on what you would do and if you just came up with that decision on your own, or it is a industry standard or whatever reason for why you use it.

1. I have a background image, it is the sky, and just a solid color that has a gradient of white to blue from bottom to top. How should I size this for my game that will be a platformer and will have big maps?

(not concerned about 1x/2x/3x I got that covered)

should I make 512x512px tiles, 100x100px tiles, should I make 1x2000px tiles??? Is it important? Should I just use 1 big image? (tiles would be used in a tile map)

What are the trade offs to consider with memory management and size of app???

2. I have a huge background image, multiple in fact that I will layer. Lets say 5 screen widths and 2 screen heights (iOS considered). The image is unique, so I'm curious if I should tile it, what size should I tile it, and how to manage these tiles (tile map?, removing and adding to scene as they enter the camera area?)

I struggle with what to do here.

thanks for any help!!! Experts please show yourself!!! Thanks!!!

Comment: That really depends on how your app works, you should try doing what you think it's the best. There's no definitive answer for that. Test performance between multiple options.

Comment: I get that the answer varies, would you have any recommendations though. I'm at the beginning of app development for this app, so it is a 2d platformer, levels are going to be bigger than the screen size, much bigger. So with that in mind, what would you do with the 2 cases I pointed out?

Comment: The answer is always it depends lol. The thing is, if you tell me far right and you tell me far left... I can figure out the grey area in between where I need to make a choice...

Comment: It is really hard for anyone to answer this, since it always depends on the app, there is no general rule for this situation.  You need to ask yourself, do I want to use more memory, or more CPU cycles.  Smaller tiles allow for less memory to be consumed, but uses more cycles. This is because you can repeat more tile patterns when using a smaller set.  Larger tiles allow for more memory to be used, but consumes less cycles.  Case in point, your sky background.  I would not want to be wasting a lot of cycles on this. I would make the tiles as large as possible but still allow for some repeats

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll keep that in mind and just play around with different sizes.